# Need RegEx Pattern to prevent ‘<’ character and ‘&#’ combination

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need a Regular Expression pattern to prevent the following character.The input string does not have any '<' character and '&#' combination. Please provide with a regex to restrict those above characters

Comment: Please don't just ask for a solution. Give it a shot yourself.

Comment: try getting an idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843407/validate-repeating-special-chars-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^(?!.*(?:<|&#))
```

This regex will fail, when it finds a "<" or "&#" in the input string.

`^` an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), matching the start of the string

`(?!...)` the [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?:...)` a [non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

`<|&#` an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), matching `<` or `&#`

**Note:** this will fail, if the input string contains newline character, because the `.` does not match them by default.

If this is an issue, change the matching behaviour of the dot:

```
^(?s)(?!.*(?:<|&#))
```

`(?s)` inline [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), to make the `.` match newline characters.

Comment: Hi Thnaks for the replay and Help

Comment: But I got below error: parsing "^(?!.*(?:<|&#)" - Not enough )'s.  I put the Expression like : validationexpression="^(?!.*(?:<|&#)">

Comment: Please help to tune this pattern

Comment: Wrote this out of my head, just add the missing closing bracket. I corrected my expression

Comment: My validationexpression="^(?!.*(?:<|&#))" but it will not allow character and other charatcter like * , /, \ and so on.. please help me what i missed or what is wrong with my code..

Comment: @user1799664, I don't know the input validator of asp.net. Maybe it needs a pattern, that matches something, try `^(?!.*(?:<|&#)).+`. The `.+` at the end will match at least one character, the negative lookahead ensures, that it fails, when there are wrong characters.